# Question about transition matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

It seems like I'm a bit confused about the transition matrices , my question are as follows:

$1.$ If $T$ is a transition matrix from a basis $B$ to the standard basis , do we have $T.v_B=v_S?$ where $v_B$ is the vector $v$ expressed in the basis $B$ and $v_S$ is the vector $v$ expressed in the standard basis.

$2.$ If $P_B$ is the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to $B$ , Is the matrix of the same linear transformation with respect to the standard basis equal to : $T.P_B.T^{-1}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes and yes. (There's some potential slight ambiguity between $T$ and $T^{-1}$ depending on what your conventions are for what it means to be the transition matrix from some basis to some other basis.)